# Embeded Google My Map - Center on Page

Tags: html, google-maps, joomla

I had to change to an embedded My Map for a business with 2 locations.  In doing so, I cannot set the height and width of the map the way I had before.  That isn't a huge issue.  But I cannot center the map on the page.  How do I accomplish that?

New HTML that is not working correctly:

```
<div class="fluid-wrapper hidden-phone" style="text-align: center;">
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zuwjqCdHTFSc.koi0qAWQnX34" width="850" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Old code that was working:

```
<div class="fluid-wrapper hidden-phone" align="center">
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d105844.34381467322!2d-84.5165869!3d34.0018888!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88f56b7fceeae357%3A0x621d85f56e1d8376!2sCherokee+Collision+Center!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1423686645744"
width="850" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

URL of embedded map: http://www.cherokeecollisioncenter.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below styles to `.fluid-wrapper iframe`

```
margin: 0 auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

The problem with your code was that you didnt have the style `right:0` and thus it took just the `left:0`. And, `margin:0 auto;` will make it centered with no margins.